# Why images are shown in an amazing but unexpected effect in Xlib?

Tags: c, image, xlib

I tried to load [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsvKm.png), but the output wasn't shown as expected (wrong size, position, and color).

Output :

[image]

The code snippet which I've tried:

```
/* I converted the image into *.ppm format, and delete the header */
/* The header looks like this: P6\n 600 600\n 255\n */

/* Read *.ppm file */
char Ppm_File[1080000];
FILE *Fp;
Fp = fopen("PHOTO", "rb");
fread(&Ppm_File, 1080000, 1, Fp);
fclose(Fp);

/* Draw *.ppm onto XImage */
Image = XCreateImage(Dsp, Vsl, 24, ZPixmap, 0, Ppm_File, 600, 600, 32, 0);
XPutImage(Dsp, Win, Gc, Image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 600);
system("sleep 10");
```

How to show the photo properly? Which code (or argument) should be changed?

Any hints and supports are appreciated.

Comment: convert last 32 to 24 in XCreateImage. In general play with that first 24 and last 32, you should get a feeling of what's wrong.

Comment: @auselen Well, I got a `Segment Fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: @auselen As the [Xlib Document](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XCreateImage.html) said, `bitmap_pad` should be 8, 16, or 32.

Comment: What is your visual set to?

Comment: Maybe you didn't quite remove the last `\n` from the header - try grabbing the last 1080000 bytes like this... `tail -c 1080000 infile.ppm > PHOTO`

Comment: @Mark Setchell The visual type of the window is `depth = 24`, `class = 4 (TrueColor)`, and `bits_per_rgb = 8`. (Ps. I'm sure that the last 1080000 bytes was grabbed.)

Comment: bits_per_rgb=8? not 24?

Comment: `bits_**per**_rgb = 8`, so `depth = 24` (8*3 = 24).

Comment: After you read the image, try setting the first 3 bytes of Ppm_File[] to 0xff 0x00 0x00 and the next 3 bytes to 0x00 0xff 0x00 and the next 3 to 0x00 0x00 0xff and see if your top left 3 pixels show up as Red Green and Blue...

Comment: Or try setting every 3rd byte in the array to 0xff and see if the image shows up red.

Comment: @Mark Setchell **I finally got the solution.** The `bitmap_pad` could not be 24, so there must add `0x00` in every 3 bytes. eg. `0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00` `0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00` `0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00` would show up red, green, and blue.